# How to append to sqlite database when the function uses variables stored in another function

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

In my program I am using tkinter as a gui and I have entries of where the user can enter an ID for a book and the name of a book to add the book to the database records (using an sqlite db)

```
def bookListEntry(event):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Append to book list")
    bookIDLabel = Label(top, text= "bookID: ").grid(row = 0)
    bookIDEntry = Entry(top).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    bookNamelabel = Label(top, text = "bookName: ").grid(row = 1)
    bookNameEntry = Entry(top).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    quitButton = Button(top, text = "Exit", command = top.destroy)
    quitButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    appendButton = Button(top, text = "Append", command = appendToBookList)
    appendButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2)


def appendToBookList():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO bookList VALUES (?, ?);",(bookIDEntry,    bookNameEntry))
    conn.commit()
```

However, I am getting the error "NameError: name 'bookIDEntry' is not defined"
I have knowledge on global and local variables and I'm prety sure it's not working as it's a local variable but I can't think of a way for appendToBookList() of knowing the values of the entries. 
Also, another problem is that I think if it worked then it may append the name of the variables in the fields in the db, rather than what is typed into the entry boxes. Any idea of how I could solve these problems? Thank you

Comment: you need to query the UI for where these items are selected.
eg, ask BookNameEntry for what it's value is

Comment: you have to use `global` variables. Or `return variables` from `bookListEntry` and later `appendToBookList(variables)`. Or create class with all code and you will use `self.`

Comment: These should be class methods. and the items like BookNameEntry should be assigned to self so that it is accessible everywhere in the class and can share the info that way.

Comment: Even if this worked, don't you have to extract the text from the `bookIDEntry` input?

Comment: btw: as @cricket_007 mentions you have to use `get()` (ie. `bookIDEntry.get()`) to get text from `Entry`. And don't use `var = Widget().grid()` because `grid()` returns `None` so in `var` you have `None` instead of expected widget.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might have to be done over OOP which I was trying to avoid as I don't have much experience with objects and classes. And yes, cricket_007 this was one of my concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested

```
def book_list_entry(event):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Append to book list")

    Label(top, text="bookID: ").grid(row=0)

    book_id_entry = Entry(top)
    book_id_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(top, text="bookName: ").grid(row=1)

    book_name_entry = Entry(top)
    book_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    b = Button(top, text="Exit", command=top.destroy)
    b.grid(row=2, column=1)

    b = Button(top, text="Append", command=lambda:append_to_bookList(book_id_entry.get(), book_name_entry.get())
    b.grid(row=2, column=2)


def append_to_bookList(book_id, book_name):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO bookList VALUES (?, ?);", (book_id, book_name))
    conn.commit()
```

---

If you need variable `var`  then you have to use

```
var = Widget(...)
var.grid(...)
```

You can't do

```
var = Widget(...).grid(...)
```

because `grid/pack/place` returns `None` and you will get `None` in `var` instead of expected widget.

If you don't need `var` than you can do

```
Widget(...).grid(...)
```

---

You have to use `entry.get()` to get text from entry

```
book_id_entry.get(), book_name_entry.get()
```

---

You can call `append_to_BookList` with arguments (text from entries) but you have to use `lambda` to create anonymouse function without variables.

```
command=lambda:append_to_bookList(book_id_entry.get(), book_name_entry.get())
```

It is similar to

```
temp_function_name = lambda:append_to_bookList(book_id_entry.get(), book_name_entry.get())

Button( ..., command=temp_function_name)
```

---

I use prefered

- `lower_case_names` for functions and varaibles.
- inside brackets `=` without spaces.

Comment: thank you I ran that code and it worked the first time! But now it has locked the database so I can't add any more books into the book list. I can't see how it's locking the database as there isn't a c.close() anywhere in the code. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @JoeW373 I don't know - you have to create new question on SO with new source code to show problem. Maybe you get some error message when you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it myself, I just put a 10 second timeout on the cursor connection and as long as you add a new record 10 seconds after the last one, everything works fine. Thank you so much for your help :)